# Layouts and images android

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.paul_2.a5aprilie;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(this);
        root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        root.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    setContentView(root);

    Button btn1= new Button(this);
    btn1.setText("Click Me");
    root.addView(btn1);

    LinearLayout linearContainer=new LinearLayout(this);
    linearContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    root.addView(linearContainer);

    final LinearLayout firstRow = new LinearLayout(this);
    firstRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    firstRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    linearContainer.addView(firstRow);

    ImageView fiora = new ImageView(this);
    fiora.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fiora);

    ImageView katarina= new ImageView(this);
    katarina.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.katarina);

    ImageView lb=new ImageView(this);
    lb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lb);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,120);
  //  params1.leftMargin =0;
  //  params1.topMargin = 0;

    firstRow.addView(fiora,params1);
    firstRow.addView(katarina,params1);
    firstRow.addView(lb,params1);

    LinearLayout secondRow = new LinearLayout(this);
    secondRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    secondRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    linearContainer.addView(secondRow);

    secondRow.addView(lb,params1);
    secondRow.addView(fiora,params1);
    secondRow.addView(katarina,params1);







    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation animSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide);

            firstRow.startAnimation(animSlide);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I want to display these images twice (in two different layouts) but works just "firstRow". When I am trying to `addView` of the images in the "secondRow" my app crashed. Can someone explain me why and how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that the added items in the second row are already attached. So you should create views one more time and add it to the second row.

Also you should change layout params of your rows like this:

```
firstRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

And maybe you have error in orientation of your LinearLayouts, because there are two columns now instead if rows.

P.S. Why do you not use xml for this purposes?

Comment: I tried but still don't appear the second row, just the first one.

Comment: I don't use XML because my university want us to do everything dynamically in java, nothing in XML is allowed. :(

Comment: Thank you so much!